# Make My Raspberry Pi Live Stream Online With A Permanent Address

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, http-live-streaming

I have successfully made a live video stream using raspberry pi3
Following this tutorial

https://github.com/Arijit1080/Live-Video-Stream-from-Raspberry-Pi-Camera-over-the-Network

And it works. What i want to do is make this availble from any where in the world. Is there any idea to do so. Currently i have to set my IP address every time i need to start streaming as it changes frequently.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What you need is a static IP address or a dyndns service. Dyndns is a service which gets updates from your device when your external IP changes. It then provides you a fixed URL to access your device and reroutes the traffic behind to your actual IP address.

Comment: DON'T port forward! I have used ngrok for this kind of thing in the past. You could also use a VPN but you have to be very careful with this sort of thing or else you will have a linux hacking machine on your network

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution Using Dataplicity. 
Dataplicity can be used easily for this.  Installing Dataplicity in our pi and configure it. We get a permanent  web url for our raspberry pi. They provide a wormhole service and by enabling it we can stream live video from anywhere in the world without even coding!